# SQL Server Simple Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: I have written it a bit wrong gill change my Q

I'm a newbie with SQL and I have a Q..

I made 2 Temp. Tables.
Each has 25 Rows.(DateValue)

I want to combine this 2 tables in a third table..
First Table is [From]
Second Table is [To]...
Both tables have different values

I want to get it like this:

```
From| To |
1111|2222
2222|3333
3333|4444
```

etc..

I use this simple Query

```
Create Table #T3
( 
   [From] Datetime
   ,[To] Datetime
)

INSERT  Into #T3
SELECT Distinct #T1.[From], #T2.[To]
From #T1,#T2
Where #T1.[From] is not null
And #T2.[To] is not null

Select * from  #T3

Drop Table #T3
Drop Table #T2
Drop Table #T1
```

But my results are like this

```
From| To |
1111|1111
1111|2222
1111|3333
2222|1111
2222|2222
2222|3333
```

It multiplies the first field with the second wich gives me alot more records back..

Any help ?
THANKS !

Comment: You are not supplying enough information.  What is in #T1, #T2?  What are the keys?  What exactly are you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Change the check to eqality check: `Where #T1.[From] = #T2.[To]`. And you probably don't need the `DISTINCT` at all.

Comment: What is the relationship between both these tables (#T1 and #T2), are their any key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After the OP's edit**

This may work as you want (which is not entirely clear):

```
INSERT INTO #T3 
  SELECT #T1.[From]
       , MIN(#T2.[To]) 
  FROM #T1
    JOIN #T2
      ON #T1.[From] < #T2.[To]
  GROUP BY #T1.[From]
```

---

Using

```
FROM T1, T2
```

results in all combinations or rows of `T1` and `T2`. It's called a cross product and (properly) used with `CROSS JOIN`, like this:

```
FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2
```

---

When you want to join the two tables based on a condition (and not get the cross product), you use a `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` (these two are same thing):

```
FROM T1 JOIN T2
  ON T1.[From] = T2.[To]
```

will get you all rows combinations where `T1.From` matches `T2.To` (on equality). I suppose you wanted to match every row of `T1` with the row of `T2` where `T2.To` was just larger than `T1.From` so I used the "smaller than" `<` operator instead of the "equality" `=` operator.

The `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` were added to get only the one with smallest `T2.To` from those rows.

Comment: @cularis: I only figured it after I noticed the OP's edit. The first time, I figured the same with you (only I removed the useless IS NULL checks).

Answer (score 0):

It would do. It will insert a copy of table 2 for each line of table 1, as you didnt say how for it to work out how to extract what you want.

Now, assuming from and to are the same.. you can do

```
INSERT  Into #T3
SELECT Distinct #T1.[From], #T2.[To]
From #T1 left join #T2 on #T1.[From]=#T2.[To]
Where #T1.[From] is not null
```

if this isnt how you mean (although having same value in both columns would seem counter productive in that sense), what other fields have you got and how would you tie the lines together.